# Suggestions and help for angular2-cli project to load data very quickly(in milliseconds)

Tags: angular

I have a layoutCmp.ts  on which several chart components(abcChartCmp.ts, bcdChartCmp.ts, defChartCmp.ts) are created(about 10 chart components in number).

These chart components are getting created on layoutCmp.ts dynamically. The chart components makes post request for the data from the server and take their data(different data from same Url) and plot their graphs.

Please help, if the approach is correct, then how to receive data quickly from server such that each components get data quickly and renders graph. How to get data from server quickly in this Scenario.

```
service.ts
-------------
getdata(JsonData): Observable<JsonData[]>{
/*---------------*/
return http.post(url, JsonData);
}

abc.component.ts
-----------------------
let jsondataabc ={
id =["brand"];
}
dataservice.getdata(jsondataabc).subscribe({
success = > this.abcChart(success );
})

abcChart(success ){
/*-------------*/
}

bcd.component.ts
-----------------------
let jsondatabcd ={
id =["state"];
}

dataservice.getdata(jsondatabcd).subscribe({
success = > this.bcdChart(success );
})

bcdChart(success ){
/*-------------*/
}

Many more components like that---------
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get simple data then use subscribers other wise if you want to add more functionality after getting the data then use Observable.

case:1 you just need simple data
case:2 you need to perform more functions on data

Comment: I am just making an ajax call using service.ts  method getdata (jsondata), which is carrying payloads as "jsondata"(post request) as parameter, then, different components are subscribing to the method getdata (jsondata) to get their respective data and thus, on success a method  abcChart(jsondata) and bcdChart(jsondata) is called for further implementations.

Comment: I want a better approach so that i can get data very fast within milliseconds